# Unable to login to visual studio from an Azure database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure

I have an Azure database that I am trying to update through Visual Studio. I am an administrator on the portal. When I am at the Azure database dashboard and select open in Visual Studio it prompts me for the password of a previous developer who is no longer on the project. When I try to enter my id and password I receive a error dialog with the following message:

[My Azure Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4dDS.png)

Answer (score 0):

in portal.azure.com, you coule go to browser, SQL servers ans find ngl7ew5ap. In properties, you should see the SERVER ADMIN LOGIN. In the SQL server > ngl7ew5ap > Settings blade, You also have the option to reset that login's password.

[image: Azure portal]

NB: In that same blade, You also have the "show firewall Settings", but that doesn't seem to be your issue for how.

Comment: I am a bit confused. When I go to the ngl7ew5ap database in the Azure Portal and it is selected I only see the DASHBOARD MONITOR SCALE CONFIGURE GEO-REPLICATION AUDITING & SECURITY tab options. I don't see the the properties option or the SERVER ADMIN LOGIN. See, I don't think I made myself clear. What happened is that the  last developer left the company and I took over. Now, even though I am now using the MSDN subscription and Azure account the previous developer's Id is displayed in the VS login when I try to open VS. What I need to do is assign myself as the VS user associated with DB.

Comment: You may not be an administrator of the SAL Database server. If so, and if you don't have access to a login which as sufficient rights, you might not be able to access the database :-(

Comment: Let me tell you what right's I have. I am an administrator of the Azure portal with an account and can login and see all of the databases. I have the login and password for the MSDN account and can login. I do have an administrator visual studio subscription account for the Azure portal. Both the old administrator and I have default directories in the left top corner user drop down menu of the main portal page. At this point should I not be able to change either the password or rights of either the current SAL Database server administrator or change myself to the SAL Database server admin?

Comment: I just added a screen shot. Can you see the same in your environment? If so you should reset the server admin login. With that login, you can then change other logins and users thru Transact-SQL, by connecting with Visual Studio at least to the master database.

Comment: My screen is not the same. My screen shot is pasted below:

Comment: I am trying to paste my screen shot but am unable. Let me figure this out and then I will.

Comment: I edited my question and added a link to my image. When I click on the link it displays the image of my Azure Home page. Please let me know if this link works to display my image.

Comment: First of all, my problem was I was using the old Azure portal. Now when I went to server and selected reset password, changed the password, updated the password I was able to login to that database and server in visual studio. Now, because the database server was being used by a running application once that happened the application could not access the database. Doing a search for connection strings in the source code I found the original password, reset it back in Azure and everything now is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the right user/pwd... Which version of Visual Studio do you use ? I remember a time where I had to connect with 'myusername@ngl7ew5ap' from Visual Studio.
I think 'myusername' should be fine for VS2015 but you may try the other syntax.
Hope this helps
Best regards
Stéphane

Comment: I am using VS 2015. The main thing I can't understand is that everything associated with the DB points to the previous developer. The connection string generated by Azure has that user's ID as part of the string and when VS tries to open that user's ID is the default id in the login dialog. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have been reading about how to create, and add permissions to Azure resources all day but am still stomped.

Comment: Ok, I read the complementary info you gave to my friend's benjamin's answer. He gave you the info to set the password from the new portal, from your answer I can tell you use the current one.

Comment: DASHBOARD MONITOR SCALE CONFIGURE GEO-REPLICATION AUDITING & SECURITY  is the view from DB - if you wish to set a new password you need to select the server not the DB - When you select the server (the one on which is your DB), go on the dashboard, you'll see the option to 'reset administrator password'. Another interesting point in your error is the n in database in url -> datanbase instead of database -> ngl7ew5ap.datanbase.windows.net - Hope this helps - Best regards - Stéphane

Comment: OK. I see that you need me to go to the current account of the Azure server and use that one and not the new one which is mine. The problem there is that I don't know the password for that account. Is there a way for me to access that server account if I don't know the previous user's password?